# Docker docker-composer.yml volume issue

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

Hi I'm having issues trying to get the following to add the volume for the webserver.

my file structure is

```
c:\dockerdev\kitchen
             db
             webserver
               - Dockerfile
             www
               - index.php
             docker-composer.yml
```

docker-composer.yml

```
 version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./webserver
    image: kitchen_web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /www:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.19
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_kitchen
```

The mysql files seem to go into the correct folder fine but when I run localhost I get the following error and it seems the volume for apache is wrong.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

```
webserver_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2017:05:27:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 500 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
webserver_1  | [Fri Sep 01 05:27:41.022526 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 15] [client 172.18.0.1:59382] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: Are you sure that directory `/www` on host contains `index.php` or `index.html` files?

Answer (score 0):

I think when your adding your www to the container, your trying to mount the wrong directory...

```
 - /www:/var/www/html
```

Should be

```
 - www:/var/www/html
```

The www directory isn't off the root, its off the current directory.

Comment: tryed that and got this error :: Step 2/2 : COPY www/ /var/www/html/
ERROR: Service 'webserver' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder163616804/www: no such file or directory

Comment: Try updating the www to c:/dockerdev/kitchen/www

Comment: was able to get it to work by moving the project to my c:/User/Username/Project folder. Seems docker/ windows is peculiar around which folders it can get access to for some things. eg nginx:
        image: nginx:1.10.2
        ports:
            - 80:80
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - c:/users/vmpwr/projects/projectX:/code
        links:
            - php
        depends_on:
            - php works fine :-)

Comment: I'll have to try using Docker on Windows, only used it on Ubuntu so far.   Useful to know - I'll bear it in mind for the future.